# Assign values in respective columns

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

In my angular 6 application i am making a table which has the following,

**Html:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Property Details &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            </th>
            <th>
                {{productOneDetails}}  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            </th>
            <th>
                {{productTwoDetails}} 
            </th>
        </tr> <br>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of mergedArray">
      <td> {{ item.property_name }} </td>
      <td> {{ item.property_value }} </td>
      <td> {{ item.property_value }} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the above i am having two arrays inside `products` object as `product one` and `product two`..

And at last i am in the need to merge both the properties `this.productOneProperties` and `this.productTwoProperties` and will display the final result in table..

Everything is working fine as of now..

**Working example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iv8ckz

Here you can see the **current result** as,

```
Property Details            Product One         Product Two

Length                        12cm                12cm
Width                         10cm                10cm
Height                        20cm                20cm
Color                         Red                 Red
Size                          Medium              Medium
```

Whereas the **expected output** is,

```
Property Details            Product One         Product Two

Length                        12cm                -
Width                         10cm                -
Height                        20cm                -
Color                         -                   Red
Size                          -                   Medium
```

So in general i need to merge both the array and display all the properties in `Property Details` column..

And **if only** the product has that property then the particular value needs to be filled other wise it should be with **"-"** symbol..

Hope you get the point what is my requirement..

Kindly help me to convert the **current output** into **expected output**.

Comment: If your property names are fixed or not?. I mean length,width,height,color,size like this.

Comment: @KarnanMuthukumar, I will come as dynamic via service.. To make stackblitz, i have hard coded here.. It will be anything that comes from service..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a type to each object in order to recognize the product. Then use condition from the template to evaluate

```
this.products.productOne.forEach(element => {
  this.productOneDetails = element.product_name; 
  this.productOneProperties = element.productOneProperties.map(item => {item.type = "one"; return item});
});
this.products.productTwo.forEach(element => {
  this.productTwoDetails = element.product_name; 
  this.productTwoProperties = element.productTwoProperties.map(item => {item.type = "two"; return item});
```

Html

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of mergedArray">
  <td> {{ item.property_name }} </td>
  <td> {{ item.type === "one" ? item.property_value: '-' }} </td>
  <td> {{ item.type === "two" ? item.property_value: '-'  }} </td>
 </tr>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-usgt75?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Is it not possible to achieve result without adding additional line to it??

Comment: u need a property to recognize which object belong to which product

Comment: @undefined check my edited answer, you have a solution without editing the .ts

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka, Can you help me in the extended question of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827050/remove-duplicate-names-in-a-column

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, in your table, you use the same property to show the variables in both columns, meaning they will always show the same.

The simplest method I can think of: **Save the product you are using on each object**. This way you can filter easily:

`ngOnInit` would look like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.products.productOne.forEach(element => {
      this.productOneDetails = element.product_name;
      this.productOneProperties = element.productOneProperties;
      this.productOneProperties.map(p => {
        p.product = 1;
      });
    });

    this.products.productTwo.forEach(element => {
      this.productTwoDetails = element.product_name;
      this.productTwoProperties = element.productTwoProperties;
      this.productTwoProperties.map(p => {
        p.product = 2;
      });
    });

    this.mergedArray = [...this.productOneProperties, ...this.productTwoProperties];
}
```

And your html's `<tr>`:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mergedArray">
  <td> {{ item.property_name }} </td>
  <td> {{ item.product === 1 ? item.property_value : "-" }} </td>
  <td> {{ item.product === 2 ? item.property_value : "-" }} </td>
</tr>
```

---

Without touching the ts it's a bit trickier, but can be done with certain conditions:

Modifying only the `<tr>`:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mergedArray">
  <td> {{ item.property_name }} </td>
  <td> {{ productOneProperties.indexOf(item) !== -1 ? item.property_value : "-" }} </td>
  <td> {{ productTwoProperties.indexOf(item) !== -1 ? item.property_value : "-" }} </td>
</tr>
```