# Remove duplicate names in a column

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

In my angular 6 application, i am making a table with the contents from `products` array like,

**Ts:**

```
  products: any = {
    "productOne": [
      {
        "id": 1, "product_name": "Product One",
        "productOneProperties": [
          { "id": 1, "property_name": "Length", "property_value": "12cm" },
          { "id": 2, "property_name": "Width", "property_value": "10cm" },
          { "id": 3, "property_name": "Height", "property_value": "20cm" },
        ]
      }
    ],

    "productTwo": [
      {
        "id": 2, "product_name": "Product Two",
        "productTwoProperties": [
          { "id": 1, "property_name": "Length", "property_value": "15cm" },
          { "id": 2, "property_name": "Width", "property_value": "12cm" },
          { "id": 2, "property_name": "Size", "property_value": "Medium" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

**Html:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Property Details &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            </th>
            <th>
                {{productOneDetails}}  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            </th>
            <th>
                {{productTwoDetails}} 
            </th>
        </tr> <br>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of mergedArray">
      <td> {{ item.property_name }} </td>
      <td> {{ item.type === "one" ? item.property_value: '-' }} </td>
      <td> {{ item.type === "two" ? item.property_value: '-'  }} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here i have two separate products and properties in which the property name such as `Length` and `Width` has **repeated** for both products with **different values**..

**Working stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9yzwss

**Current result:**

```
Property Details            Product One         Product Two

Length                      12cm                -
Width                       10cm                -
Height                      20cm                -
Length                      -                   15cm
Width                       -                   12cm
Size                        -                   Medium
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Property Details            Product One         Product Two

Length                      12cm                15cm
Width                       10cm                12cm
Height                      20cm                -
Size                        -                   Medium
```

Kindly help me to achieve the expected result by displaying the duplicate property name as unique and display the values adjacent.. If the property and value is not there then it needs to have **"-"**..

KIndly helpme to convert the **current result** into **expected result**..

Comment: but values are different for both products, still you want to remove?

Comment: @PardeepJain, You can see that in expected result that the values have gone to the top under product two.. If you compare both results you will get idea of what i mean..

Comment: Both array will on the same size?

Comment: @Justcode, No it will be dynamic according to service.. Both won't have same size..

Comment: so, when product_3 comes you will manually merge the array?

Comment: @Justcode, Here i have listed only two products but it may have many products with same or different properties.. Everything will be from service only..Here to make better understanding and clear question i have hard coded with two products..

Comment: @undefined you need to flattern your structure instead of productOneProperties you can use `properties` this way looping would be simple

Comment: @Justcode, To make a question understandable i have made it with static data..But my requirement is same as like given.. In real application i will merge all the product's properties and display it like the expected result.. How can i achieve the thing dynamically?? Please helpme out with clear solution..

Comment: @undefined you need to think about structure first then you can go structuring as your requirement, your current json data looks messy.

Comment: @undefined I added solution to your problem, have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your structure is quite wrongly added, you must consider your structure using flattern, It would be quite easier if you do so.

Let's think about handling this structure.

You need three variables defined in your component

```
  headers: any;
  data: any;  
  properties:any;
```

First you need to get the headers

```
 var headers = Object.keys(this.products).reduce((prev, next) => {
      prev.push({ name: this.products[next][0].product_name, id: next });
      return prev;
    }, []);
```

Then, get properties and data

```
 let data = [];
    let propertiesData = [];
    headers.forEach(a => {
      const properties = this.products[a.id][0][a.id + "Properties"];
      data.push({id:a,properties:properties});
      propertiesData.push(properties);
    });
```

Then assign this variables to the header,data and properties

```
propertiesData = propertiesData.flat().filter((thing, index, self) =>
      index === self.findIndex((t) => (
        t.property_name === thing.property_name
      ))
    )

    this.headers = headers;
    this.data = data;
    this.properties = propertiesData;
```

So, you have three things now, headers data and properties which are unique,

Now, you need one method which will filter out this property names against the data,

```
 getPropertyData(propertyName,item){        
    var value= item.properties.filter(a=> a.property_name === propertyName);
    if(value.length>0){
      return value[0].property_value;
    }else{
      return "-";
    }
  }
```

Now, in your view you can restructure your table to like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Property Details
            </th>
            <th *ngFor="let item of headers">
                {{item.name}}
            </th>
        </tr> <br>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of properties">
      <td>{{item.property_name}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let itemData of data">
        {{getPropertyData(item.property_name,itemData)}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So, this will filter out the properties data against the products.

Here is the [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/flatternstructure). remember there are some drawbacks using the structure. like your third property must be a name of `productThreeProperties`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185491/discussion-on-answer-by-just-code-remove-duplicate-names-in-a-column).

Comment: Please helpme out in this scenario alone Why i am getting error in this stackblitz?? https://stackblitz.com/edit/flatternstructure-mc3zjq .. The thing i have added is made another object inside ```template_details``` array.. And given ```a.template_information.template_details[index]``` instead of ```a.template_information.template_details[0]``` because i may have multiple ```template_details``` as it is an array..

Answer (score 1):

[Something like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f6yl6h)

There's probably a better way of formatting the data, but the idea should be pretty much the same.
Alternatively you could just try to format the objects in the following format:

```
[ 
{ "propName": "length", "one": 12, "two": 20 },
{ "propName": "width", "one": 12, "two": '-'}
...
]
```

Or combining the "one" and "two" into an array to make expansion easier.

Comment: What will happen if i have many number of products and not two??

Comment: For n products, You'd probably want to have something like a productArray = ['one', 'two' ... ] and do <td *ngFor="let product of productArray"> {{ getPropertyVal(product , property) }} </td>

Answer (score 0):

the result is not correct because your merging the product logic is wrong. i having done some minor changes to show how you can correct the data to show what you want.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.mergedProductProperties = {};
  this.products.productOne.forEach(element => {
    this.productOneDetails = element.product_name;
    element.productOneProperties.type  = "one";

    element.productOneProperties.forEach(item => {
      this.mergedProductProperties[item.property_name] =this.mergedProductProperties[item.property_name] || [];
      this.mergedProductProperties[item.property_name][0] = item.property_value;
     });
   });

  this.products.productTwo.forEach(element => {
    this.productTwoDetails = element.product_name;
     element.productTwoProperties.type  = "two";

     element.productTwoProperties.forEach(item => {
       this.mergedProductProperties[item.property_name] = this.mergedProductProperties[item.property_name] || [];
       this.mergedProductProperties[item.property_name][1] = item.property_value;
     });
   });
  console.log(this.mergedProductProperties);
  for(var key in this.mergedProductProperties){
     this.mergedArray.push({
       property_name: key,
       property_value: this.mergedProductProperties[key]
     })
  }
  console.log(this.mergedArray);
}
```

html will be change by

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of mergedArray">
  <td> {{ item.property_name }} </td>
    <td *ngFor="let val of item.property_value">{{val}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```